# Android - achieve dimming of background effect

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a splash screen with a dimmed background. Im using `RelativeLayout` as the base for all the widgets. In order to create and dim effect I created  a `dim.xml`, which is essentially a black shape (to set the opacity later).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
```

The layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:id="@+id/ActivityLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="170dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:id="@+id/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a way to place the black shape between the `RelativeLayout` and the widgets, and then set some alpha value to the black shape in order to achieve the dimming effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to place the black shape between the RelativeLayout and
>   the widgets, and then set some alpha value to the black shape in order
>   to achieve the dimming effect?

You can achieve this by adding another `View` in your RelativeLayout and set its width and height to "match_parent", then change the View's background color to what you want.

Your layout may go like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  ...  
>

<View android:width="match_parent"
      android:height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/the_color_you_want"/>

<here are the widgets...>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update:**

> But it doesnt fill the entire view port, the there's about 10dp margin
>   on each side, that doesnt stretches across the screen. Any way to fill
>   the entire screen?

It's because you have set a 10dp padding for both the left and right side of your `RelativeLayout`. There are two ways to make the color View fill the entire screen:

1. Set `android:clipToPadding="false"` to your `RelativeLayout` and then set the following attribute to the color View:

> android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
>   android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"

This is very easy to do but it may cause problem to your widgets, so you can have a try.

2. Remove `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` attribute from your `RelativeLayout`, thus your color `View` will fill the screen, then rearrange your widgets to make sure their left or right margin is correct.

You may need to do more work with this method, but I'm sure this is a right way.

Comment: That is almost perfect! But it doesnt fill the entire view port, the there's about 10dp margin on each side, that doesnt stretches across the screen. Any way to fill the entire screen?

Comment: Awesome. What the best method to assure that there will be no margin\padding on all devices? (if i set mamrginLeft=-10, for example, how will the app run on a wider device?)

Comment: @undroid "-10dp" is just appropriate because your @dimen/activity_horizontal_margin may be 10dp, so it will work on all devices because the sum of those two number equals zero. And I recommend the second method as a better solution.

Comment: Great, I used the second recommendation and it worked like a charm.